# COde to Generate Sequential Number Each time when prefix is changes

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform whose image is shown below.

[image]

The data entry sheet image is also attached.

[image]

***Command Button*** Code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet, tbl As ListObject, row As ListRow

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table2")
Set row = tbl.ListRows.Add

prefix = Me.TextBox1.Value & "-"

Dim NextNum As Long, LastRow As Long, lRow As Long, myArr() As Long

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    'Find Last Row in Voucher # Column
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).row

    ReDim myArr(1 To LastRow)
    ' read all cells contents and convert them to array of numbers
    For lRow = 5 To LastRow
        If Mid(.Cells(lRow, 5), 4) <> "" Then
            myArr(lRow) = CLng(Mid(.Cells(lRow, 5), 4))
        End If
    Next lRow

    ' find maximum value in array
    NextNum = WorksheetFunction.Max(myArr)
End With
row.Range(1, 1).Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value
row.Range(1, 2).Value = prefix & NextNum + 1
row.Range(1, 3).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value

End Sub
```

When i press the command button, it will generate the sequence number with the prefix. But i want when the prefix is changed, it should read the number attached with that prefix and then generate the next number.

Sample Result is attached.
[image]

Comment: @ Shai Please advise how can i achieve this...

Comment: I don't understand the flow of your data,where the prefix changed ? worksheet or user_form ? where is the number being entered ?

Comment: In text box 1 prefix needs to be entered.

Comment: Like Abc-# after 3 or 4 entries if i change the prefix the number should be start from 1

Comment: can you edit your post, and upload a sample of data in your worksheet, before and after a change like that (make a manual simulation and add the screen-shots)

Comment: i have attached the sample data...

Comment: I tried to understand, but I couldn't, not sure what changes to what. Try reading your post as someone who doesn't know anything about what you are trying to achieve , will he understand what you are trying to do ?